# If Statement not working

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner, println

I am new to programming and would appreciate some help. The slightest bit of insight would be highly appreciated. 
I have an issue with the following code. The program emulates a calculator but currently my main focus is on if and else if statements. **The issue is that no matter what the user selects, the program will always add the two numbers i.e. 'number1' and 'number2' in the code**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Input
{
    private Scanner input;

    public Input()
    { 
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

    }

    public void calculation()
    {
        double number1, number2, answer;
        String A, B, C, D, E;
        String option;
        A = "A"; B = "B"; C = "C"; D = "D"; E = "E"; //initialising the strings 

        System.out.println("add - option A \t (if your option is A, insert 'A')");
        System.out.println("multiply - option B");
        System.out.println("subtract - option C");
        System.out.println("divide - option D");
        System.out.println("power - option E (1st number - 'X' & 2nd number - 'n' following X^n)");
        System.out.println("Remember Java is case sensitive, therefore, inserting 'a' as 'A' won't work");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Insert your first number: ");
        number1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Insert your second number: ");
        number2 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Choosing option: ");
        option = input.next();

        if(A == A)
        {
            answer = number1 + number2;
            System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);
        }

        else if(B == B)
        {
            answer = number1 * number2;
            System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);

        }else if(C == C)
        {
            answer = number1 - number2;
            System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);

        }else if(D == D)
        {
            answer = number1 / number2;
            System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);

        }else if(E == E)
        {
            answer = Math.pow(number1, number2);
            System.out.println("Your answer is: " + answer);

        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Choose a suitable option");

        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Any object is always `==` to itself.

Comment: Did you mean `A == "A"`? That would be wrong too.

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`, instead use `string.equals(...)`

Comment: You probably mean `option == A` and so on..

Comment: @karthikr In which case it would still be `.equals()`.

Comment: Your `if` statement appears to be working just fine. `A == A` is always `true` and, as the `if` statement should, it executes the code in that block. By the way, you can use `String` expressions in `switch` statements these days.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is not a duplicate of that question (as `A.equals(A)` vs. `A == A` is not the root problem right now), although the OP's *next* question after he fixes his general logic errors will most likely be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @JasonC Are they not implicitly asking how to compare Strings?

Comment: @RobertH so how would the 'string.equals' look? I assume i put it within the circle brackets within the if statements and then insert one of the fields i have defined?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well, I personally don't think so. The way I see it, the OP is having a more fundamental problem conceptualizing the logic of his program, mostly as evidenced by `A==A`, `B==B`, instead of an attempt at `option==A`, `option==B`. So there seems to be a deeper issue with his thought process that could be addressed in answers here but is not addressed by a general question regarding string comparison. As it stands, `A.equals(A)` and `B.equals(B)` would not solve his problem alone. It's up for interpretation. Once the OP gets the logic down, *then* the string question is next.

Comment: @JasonC My initial attempt was with option==A and so on but whenever i run the program it jumps straight to the else statement

Comment: Well in that case, your problem most certainly was "how do I compare strings?" and @SotiriosDelimanolis duplicate link contains the information you would have needed.

Comment: @JasonC I'm just busting balls :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Youre getting the selected option from user input in `option = input.next();` line and than your not using it in your if statements.

Instead of `if(A == A)` use `if(option.equals(A))` and so on for other cases.